# what effect does <form> tags have vue.js' rendering process and recativity system?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, rendering, vue-reactivity

I discovered the form tags in a vue.js app was breaking the render. the app is a quiz, which pulls questions from a local json document when setting the form up, questions are stored with vuex and are brought into component with computed properties. interestingly the quiz would move to second quiz before crashing with render errors. however when i remove the form tags the quiz proceeds to completion.

obviously not ideal to remove form tags since they are useful for assistive technologies. so what roll does form tags or semantic html tags in general play with vue's recativity system or rendering process? I've read the caveats in the guide, which don't seem to address this situation.

below is the form component and vuex

**form component**

```
<template>
    <div class="form">
        <h4><b>{{question.question}}</b></h4>
        <div id="form-layout">
            <form >
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" v-model="answer" value="a">
                    <label for="one">{{question.multiple_choice[0].a}}</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" v-model="answer" value="b">
                    <label for="two">{{question.multiple_choice[0].b}}</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" v-model="answer" value="c">
                    <label for="three">{{question.multiple_choice[0].c}}</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" v-model="answer" value="d">
                    <label for="four">{{question.multiple_choice[0].d}}</label>
                </p>
                <button @click="submitQuestion">submit answer</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button @click="$emit('submitQuiz')">submit quiz</button>
    </div>
</template>
    <script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    questionNumber: 0,
                    answer: ''
                }
            },
            computed: {
                getQuestions() {
                    return this.$store.getters['QuizModule/getQuestionsArray']
                },
                question() {
                    return this.getQuestions[this.questionNumber]
                }
            },
            methods: {
                submitQuestion: function() {
                    // check answer
                    // reset form
                    this.questionNumber += 1
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**vuex**

```
import questionBank from '@/question-bank/practice.json'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      questionsArray: null,
    },
    getters: {
      getQuestionsArray: function (state) {
          return state.questionsArray
      },
      getQuestion: state => {
        const questions = state.questionsArray
        return index => {
          return questions[index]
        }
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      setQuestionsArray (state, questions) {
          state.questionsArray = questions
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async setQuestionsArray ({commit}, questionArray){
            try {
                let questions = []
                for(let i = 0; i < questionArray.length; i++){
                    questions[i] = questionBank[questionArray[i]]
                }
                commit('setQuestionsArray', questions)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
  })

export default store
```

Comment: As far as Vue is concerned I'm 99.99999% it doesn't care one bit. I'm using `<form>` in one of my websites and it works just fine.What specific errors do you get?

Comment: Render breaks and displays nothing, console error “TypeError: cannot read property ‘0’ of null”

Comment: As far as I can tell that's due to the fact that `questionsArray` is set to null and isn't being updated correctly

Comment: So questionsArray should be set to an uninitialized array instead of null, and somehow that combined with the form tags is breaking hmm I’ll try when I get back home

Comment: I'd suggest initializing it as something you know what it is so that TypeError comes back with whatever you made it, that way you know if the problem is that it's not being updated. Like, I think your problem is the code that gets the form data, e.g. that you've used the class as a top level selector and select children of the class to get the form data or something, and adding <form> screws up the child selecting.

Comment: not capturing any form data yet, so thats not the issue. changing the initialization from null to anything else didnt make a difference

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the issue might be, sorry. All I know is that I can use `<form>` without any issues on my websites so at least to my knowledge it shouldn't be the `<form>` tag itself being an issue for Vue but something else in your code.